# Time Settings Problem

Tags: settings, time

I use Windows(occasionally) and Linux(always) on my laptop. When I switch back to Windows, the time changes. If it is 11 a.m., when I switch to windows, it shows 10 a.m. Why does this problem occur and is there any way to fix it?